# What does getblocktemplate return?

Tags: daemon, rpc, getblocktemplate

Looking on the forum, it seems that `getblocktemplate` RPC call returns both a `blockhashing_blob` and `blocktemplate_blob`, but on the *monerod documentation* i didn't find anything about the `blockhashing_blob`.

As i understood, it returns a `blocktemplate_blob`, that is an entire block blob, with a reserverd field (nonce), that you can change trying to make the block hash below the target.
It seems to be complete with miner coinbase transaction, and all the other stuff belonging to a block.

Is there anything that i didn't catch?

Answer (score 1):

`blockhashing_blob` is the block header and Merkle tree root hash. The block header has a nonce field and it is this a miner updates and then hashes the blockhashing_blob (which contains the header and updated nonce).

`blocktemplate_blob` is the whole block with transactions (including any requested reserved space). Nobody hashes the `blocktemplate_blob` directly, rather, they use this to create a `blockhashing_blob` to hash.

The reason both are returned from `getblocktemplate` is because a miner / pool / proxy may want to *modify* the block's reserved space before creating the `blockhashing_blob`. This reserved space can only be easily changed *before* creating the `blockhashing_blob` because you need to know it's offset. Conversely, the nonce can be updated in the `blockhashing_blob` directly because it's at a fixed location.

Lastly, it is the updated `blocktemplate_blob` that's submitted back to the network when a successful hash is found. This has been updated to include the successful nonce and any reserved data. Setting aside other validation, other nodes simply convert the submitted `blocktemplate_blob` to a hashing blob, hash then check resulting hash meets the difficulty target. I.e. they do not need to edit anything.